# Washing Once or Twice

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, netilat-yadayim-washing

1. Someone told me that technically one needs to pour water on each hand only once since we use large quantities of water. Is there a *halachic* source for this?
2. I heard that the requirement to pour twice over each hand (i.e. washing for bread), is really when you have only a *revi’is* of water (about three ounces) for both hands. Is there a *halachic* source for this?

Comment: See the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch

Comment: Do you have seforim available to you?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14648/759

Answer (score 1):

The primary source for this is the Mishna - מסכת ידיים - Chapter 2 Mishna 1:

> נָטַל לְיָדוֹ אַחַת מִשְּׁטִיפָה אַחַת, יָדוֹ טְהוֹרָה. לִשְׁתֵּי יָדָיו מִשְּׁטִיפָה אַחַת, רַבִּי מֵאִיר מְטַמֵּא, עַד שֶׁיִּטּוֹל מֵרְבִיעִית.